# Swift equivalent data structure in Kotlin

Tags: android, swift, data-structures, kotlin

I'm an Android developer and I don't have much exposure in `Swift` or `Kotlin`.    Recently I'm working with a `Socket.Io` client (Mirroring the existing iOS app) and found the snippet.

```
// swift code snippet    
socket.emit("joinRoom", ["room": roomName])
```

**Question:** How can I represent the above line of code in kotlin especially the second parameter `(["room": roomName])`

**More clearly:** What kind of data type can be use to represent the second parameter.

```
// Server Implementation
 socket.on("joinRoom", function (data) {
        console.log("Got 'joinRoom' from client , " + JSON.stringify(data));
        sub.subscribe(data.room);
        socket.join(data.room);    
    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`["room": roomName]` is a Dictionary in Swift. Kotlin equivalent is a Map.

```
val map = mapOf("room" to roomName)
```

Comment: To be more explicit you could also say `val map: Map<String, String> = mapOf("room" to roomName)`.